# AWS CloudFormation: Configuring replication for an existing S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I have an existing S3 bucket that I cannot delete/recreate (this bucket is not tracked in an existing CloudFormation stack; it was created manually).

I'd like to use CloudFormation to add a replication configuration to the bucket (replicating objects to another bucket).

I see in the [CloudFormation documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-replicationconfiguration.html) that you can specify the replication configuration when you create a new bucket.

Is there any way, though, to use CloudFormation to set a replication configuration on a bucket that already exists?

Comment: If this is Terraform, I think you can import your S3 bucket. Never try to import resources with CloudFormation so I just google and get this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/ , https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [import your bucket to CloudFormation (CFN)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) before you can manage it using CFN. Once you do this, you will be able to setup replication for it from CFN.

Comment: What if a bucket was created by another cloud formation stack?

Comment: @Arsen I believe you'd have to add the replication configuration settings to it within the stack it's created in. There are _technically_ other ways to do it - eg. by writing a custom resource that goes and configures replication settings - but it's probably not a good idea as it'd be too easy to override it in the existing stack.

Answer (score -1):

I do have S3 bucket ARNs, and I do have IAM which can be used to grant permission to replicate S3 buckets to different AWS accounts.
There is no CFT that can create replication rules in existing S3